# PHP loop not printing colour name according to div colour code

Tags: php

I am trying to echo the colour name of a div according to a colour code within a loop but it doesn't seem to be working. This is what I'm getting:

[image]

The color of the box should correlate with the text within it. Is there anything I'm doing wrong? This is my code so far:

```
$availColour = array("#F00","#FF0","#0D0");

for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++) {
    $Monday = $availColour[array_rand($availColour, 1)];        
    echo '<div class="innerTbl" style="width: 50px; float: left; 
    background-color: '.$Monday.'">';
    if ($Monday = "#F00") {
        echo "Red";
    }
    elseif ($Monday = "#FF0") {
        echo "Green";
    }
    elseif ($Monday = "#0D0") {
        echo "Yellow";
    }
    echo "</div>";
```

Comment: all Monday's should be red.. hate mondays...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is you mixed up `=` and `==`.

```
if ($Monday = "#F00") {
```

should be

```
if ($Monday == "#F00") {
```

To prevent this in the future, many do this.

```
if ("#F00" == $Monday) {
```

It may look awkward at first, but it can prevent you mixing them up as if you mistype your statement as

```
if ("#F00" = $Monday) {
```

Your interpreter will just die with a fatal error, complaining about you cannot assign to a constant, something like that -- this actually make your mistake much more visible.

btw, `#FF0` is yellow and `#0D0` is green, it looks like you also swapped the text too.

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing equality `==` and assignment `=`. When testing the equality of two or values, you do so with two `==` (unless you're testing type as well, in which case you'd use `===`). Additionally, your code could be simplified if you use your initial array as a lookup for your written color names:

```
$i = 9; 
$c = array( 
    "Red"   => "#F00", 
    "Green" => "#FF0", 
               "#0D0"
);

while ( $i-- ) {
    $hex = $c[ array_rand( $c ) ];
    $str = array_search( $hex, $c ) ?: "Unknown" ;
    echo "<div style='background-color:{$hex}'>{$str}</div>";
}
```

The above will use the hex value in the CSS, and (if present) the readable string within the `div` itself. If no string is provided (such is the case with `#0D0`) "Unknown" will be substituted.

This particular use of the ternary operator requires PHP version 5.3+.

Comment: except it only prints out the color String (array value) which is less than what he asked for and since not all colors are available in this format in CSS

Comment: @MohdMoe That is what his code appears to be doing. No indication is given that his code should print out a name for any given hex value.

Comment: only because you have not tested his code, he took the hex out of the array and printed it in the CSS then he checked its value to add the color name inside the div which was the main issue, if he wanted only the string name, he would've just put that instead of the hex values in the array, no need for check and  compare at all

Comment: @MohdMoe I'm really not following you here. The OP grabs a random item from the color index. This is a hex value. The OP then proceeds to echo out the opening tag for a `div`. Then, a series of `if` statements test the hex value and echos a readable color when a match is found. The closing `div` tag is then provided. That is exactly what my code above does.

Comment: his array was `array("#F00","#FF0","#0D0");` and he was setting `$Moday` to a random value out of that which would return a hex, echos it in the CSS style attr, **AND THEN** test using the if for each value and print out the color names which he set manually inside the if else check. and by the way it would be better for you to double checked the code instead of arguing.

Comment: you are, instead of double checking, i thought correction should not be taken personally, and it is for the community sake. I am still a beginner and i spend long hours reading answers by users in your reputation. but this is just silly

Comment: @MohdMoe No argument here. I appreciate you pointing out my mistake. I've updated my solution above to take into consideration your valid and much-appreciated points.

Comment: I just got my commenting permission so im using it on you `^_^`

Answer (score 2):

you are using the assign `=` instead of the compare `==`

so change

`if ($Monday = "#F00")`

into

`if ($Monday == "#F00")`

and a better way to achieve that is not using the compare at all.

```
<?php
$availColour = array("#F00"=>"Red","#FF0"=>"Green","#0D0"=>"Yellow");
for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++) {
    #get a random (key from the array);
    $key = array_rand($availColour, 1);       
    echo '<div class="innerTbl" style="width: 50px; float: left; 
    background-color: '.$key.';">';
    #directly print out the value of the selected $key
    echo $availColour[$key];
    echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your conditionals - you need to use == to test for equality. Currently, your conditionals are assigning the value, so the first condition will always evaluate as true.

Try this:

```
if ($Monday == "#F00") {
    echo "Red";
}
elseif ($Monday == "#FF0") {
    echo "Green";
}
elseif ($Monday == "#0D0") 
{
    echo "Yellow";
}
```